# Background image not responsive, gets bigger when I resize browser

Tags: css, responsive-design, background-image

I'm working on a website that has sections with text on one side and a background image on the other. In one section everything is working fine. When I resize my browser the background image is responsive and scales down. But in the next section, the background image is not responsive, the image actually gets bigger when I resize my browser and I have no idea why. (I've only been learning how to code for about a month so I'm  hoping the answer is glaringly obvious)

Here's the css from the section that works:

```
#welcome {
    margin-top: 34px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    height: 120vh;
    background-color: #dae7e9;
  }

#welcome .box1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 55%;
  height: 120vh;
}

#welcome .box2 {
  width: 45%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/c6txf7Y/Gabriel-Venneri1-3.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

And here's the css from the section that doesn't:

```
#about {
  background-color: #5d5c61;
}

#about h1 {
  color: #123c69;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#about .box1 {
  width: 40%;
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/k6mNw42/IMG-6333-2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#about .box2 {
  width: 60%;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<section id="about">
    <div class="container-1">
      <div class="box1"></div>
      <div class="box2">
        <h1>About</h1>
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I've been trying to find a solution for a week and a half so any help would be greatly appreciated

Here is a link to the site, the about section image is the issue: https://codepen.io/gvenn/full/XWNzeqW

Comment: Hi, you've given the welcome div a height, but not the about div. Does that make a difference? It would be great if you could make your code into a working snippet which shows the problem - it make it easier for people to grasp what is happening.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. I can't even figure out how to make my code into a working snippet so I've just included a link to the site

Comment: Seems the element still has quite a bit of height so the system has to 'expand' your face to cover it, given it's now quite narrow. Will look further.